# How to create sequences of dates in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a large number of urls with file.path() I have the base but need to add on dates from 2005/01 to 2018/12 in the format by the month

I would like to get

```
"2005/01","2005/02","2005/03"
```

and so on until

```
"2018/11", "2018/12"
```

I'm quite new to r and this seems like it should be simple but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `seq` on a `Date` class element (`from`, `to`) and specify the `by` as "1 month" along

```
out <- format(seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"),
          by = "1 month"), "%Y/%m")
head(out)
#[1] "2005/01" "2005/02" "2005/03" "2005/04" "2005/05" "2005/06"
tail(out)
#[1] "2018/07" "2018/08" "2018/09" "2018/10" "2018/11" "2018/12"
```